# A MATCH_PARENT view inside a WRAP_CONTENT view

Tags: android, android-layout

I understand that `MATCH_PARENT` means that the View wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding), and `WRAP_CONTENT` means that the View wants to be just big enough to enclose its content (plus padding)

My question is, what happens when a `MATCH_PARENT` view (view A) is put inside a `WRAP_CONTENT` view (view B)? How are the parameters of the two views A and B calculated in this case?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It fills all the space possible allowed for its parents, looking up on the hierarchy.

If the parent of the WRAP_CONTENT view (View B) has a size limit, it will take that size.

If no hierarchical parent has size (all are wrap_content until the root view) it will take up the whole screen.

Comment: by "it" do you mean view A?

Comment: Both. View A will fill the maximum size possible and view B will then take the same size.