# Different behaviour of "Match_parent" in LinearLayout and RelativeLayout - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Similar to this question 
[A MATCH_PARENT view inside a WRAP_CONTENT view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438696/a-match-parent-view-inside-a-wrap-content-view).

Generally I understand the answer in the above question. However I can not apply the answer to my contrived example(below) and the layout behavior seems to be different in `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` container.

Firstly I use a `LinearLayout` as container viewA, and a `Button as child viewB, The viewA is set to be`"wrap_content"`and viewB being`"march_parent".` the result is a small button at top left.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- container View A -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- child View B -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="test" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Then I tried a `RelativeLayout` as container viewA, I found the button take the whole window. So my question is that, with all the layout properties being same, why there is such a difference?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- container View A changed to RelativeLayout -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- child View B -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="test" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: **1** First of, you don't need the **A** container at all. Just set the button as `wrap_content` and that's it. **2**, Yes, Linear and Relative layouts behave differently, or they would have been the same thing.

Comment: Yes , I know A is not needed , this is a contrived example. And if I apply the answer from the other question, I would expect the result of RelativeLayout. So maybe more appropriate question is: why the LinearLayout do not follow the rule.

Comment: Let's say that the LinearLayout is **stronger willing** and imposes its rules It says "I said wrap_content and don't break my balls". The RelativeLayout is **easy going** and accomodates to its children wills. It says "do what you want and I'll wrap around you"

Comment: I see. You mean there is no specific rule to follow. It would be unpredictable and just try it.

Comment: No. I say that LinearLayout rules over its children, while children rule over RelativeLayout.