# Why RelativeLayout height set to wrap_content taking the full screen?

Tags: android, layout

Why RelativeLayout height set to wrap_content taking the full screen height if its main child height is match_parent,but LinearLayout height set to wrap_content is taking height as much as its inner child height even if main child height is match_parent.Can any one explain in detail?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/recyc_image_height"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:text="Taylor Swift"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

but linear layout,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/recyc_image_height"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:text="Taylor Swift"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: `match_parent` inside `wrap_content` is supposed to take all available space. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438696/a-match-parent-view-inside-a-wrap-content-view

Comment: But if the parent layout is LinearLayout,this is not happening.Why so?

Comment: It's just how Google decided to implement LinearLayout (for which I guess it's easier to measure the children, as they are in a linear sequence).

Comment: ok..thanks..now it is kind of clear.